# How to get a random between 1 - 100 from randDouble in Java?

Tags: java, random

Okay, I'm still fairly new to Java. We've been given an assisgnment to create a game where you have to guess a random integer that the computer had generated. The problem is that our lecturer is insisting that we use:

```
double randNumber = Math.random();
```

And then translate that into an random integer that accepts 1 - 100 inclusive. I'm a bit at a loss. What I have so far is this:

```
//Create random number 0 - 99
double randNumber = Math.random();
d = randNumber * 100;

//Type cast double to int
int randomInt = (int)d;
```

However, the random the lingering problem of the random double is that 0 is a possibility while 100 is not. I want to alter that so that 0 is not a possible answer and 100 is. Help?

Answer (score 21):

or

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomInt = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
```

Answer (score 18):

You're almost there. Just add 1 to the result:

```
int randomInt = (int)d + 1;
```

This will "shift" your range to `1 - 100` instead of `0 - 99`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) class provides the [`int nextInt(int origin, int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int)) method to get a random integer in a range:

```java
// Returns a random int between 1 (inclusive) & 101 (exclusive)
int randomInt = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 101)
```

`ThreadLocalRandom` is one of several ways to generate random numbers in Java, including the older [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#random()) method and [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html) class.  The advantage of `ThreadLocalRandom` is that it is specifically designed be used within a single thread, avoiding the additional thread synchronization costs imposed by the other implementations.  Therefore, it is usually the best built-in random implementation to use outside of a security-sensitive context.

> When applicable, use of `ThreadLocalRandom` rather than shared `Random` objects in concurrent programs will typically encounter much less overhead and contention.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean and working way to do it, with range checks! Enjoy.

```
public double randDouble(double bound1, double bound2) {
        //make sure bound2> bound1
        double min = Math.min(bound1, bound2);
        double max = Math.max(bound1, bound2);
        //math.random gives random number from 0 to 1
        return min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
    }
```

//Later just call:

```
randDouble(1,100)
//example result:
//56.736451234
```

Answer (score 1):

I will write
int number = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);

Answer (score -1):

```
    double random = Math.random();

    double x = random*100;

    int y = (int)x + 1; //Add 1 to change the range to 1 - 100 instead of 0 - 99

    System.out.println("Random Number :");

    System.out.println(y);
```